# Lighthouse Mobile scores does not cross 90 (currently ~85). Struggling from the past few days how to get this right

Tags: performance, web, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights, google-pagespeed-insights-api

Mobile scores does not cross 90. The reason given: the main-thread work. But, I've even reduced the components being displayed by using "display: none" for certain section on mobile. Despite that doesn't alter at all. What should I be doing? The following link will yield the scores:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to check your google page speed insight, I believe you are not able to cross 90+ because of Avoid chaining critical requests. If you are using WordPress. The solution is to install (https://wordpress.org/plugins/swap-google-font-display/) this plug in and it will take care of the issue.

Comment: Your answer helped quite a bit! The site was custom built so had to figure out a solution manually!

Comment: Thanks. let me know if I can more helpful in another way regarding core web vital issues.